# Spark MLlib Association Rules confidence is greater than 1.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I was using Spark 2.0.2 to extract some association rules from some data, while when I get the result, I found I have some strange rules, such as the followings：

`【[MUJI,ROEM,西单科技广场] => Bauhaus ] 2.0`

“2.0” is the confidence of the rule printed, isn't it the meaning of "the probability of antecedent to consequent" and should be less than 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**KEY WORD**: transactions != freqItemset

**SOLUTIONS**: Use spark.mllib.FPGrowth instead, it accepts a rdd of  transactions and can automatically calculate freqItemsets.

Hello, I found it. The reason of this phenomenon is because my input FreqItemset data **freqItemsets** is wrong. Let's to into detail. I simply use three original **transactions** ("a"),("a","b","c"),("a","b","d"), the frequency of them are all the same 1.

At the beginning, I thought spark would auto calculate sub-itemset frequency, the only thing I need to do is to create freqItemsets like this (the official example show us):

```
val freqItemsets = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  new FreqItemset(Array("a"), 1),
  new FreqItemset(Array("a","b","d"), 1),
  new FreqItemset(Array("a", "b","c"), 1)
))
```

Here is the reason why it make mistakes, AssociationRules's params is FreqItemset, not the **transactions**, so I made a wrong understand of these two definition.

According to the three transactions, the freqItemsets should be

```
new FreqItemset(Array("a"), 3),//because "a" appears three times in three transactions
  new FreqItemset(Array("b"), 2),//"b" appears two times
  new FreqItemset(Array("c"), 1),
  new FreqItemset(Array("d"), 1),
  new FreqItemset(Array("a","b"), 2),// "a" and "b" totally appears two times
  new FreqItemset(Array("a","c"), 1),
  new FreqItemset(Array("a","d"), 1),
  new FreqItemset(Array("b","d"), 1),
  new FreqItemset(Array("b","c"), 1)
  new FreqItemset(Array("a","b","d"), 1),
  new FreqItemset(Array("a", "b","c"), 1)
```

You can do this statistical work your self use the following code

```
val transactons = sc.parallelize(
Seq(
  Array("a"),
  Array("a","b","c"),
  Array("a","b","d")
))

val freqItemsets = transactions
.map(arr => {
        (for (i <- 1 to arr.length) yield {
          arr.combinations(i).toArray
        })
          .toArray
          .flatten
      })
      .flatMap(l => l)
      .map(a => (Json.toJson(a.sorted).toString(), 1))
      .reduceByKey(_ + _)
      .map(m => new FreqItemset(Json.parse(m._1).as[Array[String]], m._2.toLong))


//then use freqItemsets like the example code
val ar = new AssociationRules()
  .setMinConfidence(0.8)
val results = ar.run(freqItemsets)
//....
```

Simply we can use **FPGrowth** instead of "AssociationRules", it accepts rdd of transactions.

```
val fpg = new FPGrowth()
  .setMinSupport(0.2)
  .setNumPartitions(10)
val model = fpg.run(transactions) //transactions is defined in the previous code
```

That's all.